# Visual Studio 2017 dot net core solutions backwards compatibility with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, downgrade

For personal reasons, my team can't migrate all developers to visual studio 2017.
For this reason, we are looking for a way to keep the dot.net core Projects working at same time with visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2017.

Have some way to safe work like it? if not ... how can we downgrade dot.net core solution to be compatible with visual studio 2015?

please see that we have already an very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944571/is-visual-studio-2017-rc-backwards-compatible-with-visual-studio-2015-solutions) but this does not answer if is possible to downgrade the project or hack the vs15 to work with .csproj in dot.net core apps

Thanks for you time!

Comment: It does actually answer your question, you just may not want to hear/realize that. There is no way to automatically convert csproj to xproj + project.json. You'd have to do it manually or restore from SCM. Imho best is to stay at 2015 until you can upgrade all machines. In theory you could have 2 SLN files which reference the xproj/csproj respectively, but I fear the project.json may cause issues in vs2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer your questions directly :

- You cannot open CSProj .net core projects in Visual Studio 2015
- You cannot downgrade a CSProj .net core project back to Project.json

Now, you can run two .net core SDKs side by side on a single machine allowing developers who have the latest SDK installed to still be able to run a project.json project.

To do so, you need to go here https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md and download the SDK of "1.1 with SDK Preview 2.1 build 3177". This is the last SDK to support project.json.

When creating your project, in the root of your solution fodler you need to create a file called global.json and put the following inside :

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003177"
  }
}
```

Now when Visual Studio 2015 opens the project and runs tooling, it knows to use the old project.json tooling.

Further reading : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/02/17/developing-two-versions-net-core-sdk-side-side/