# Visual Studio 2017 wants to upgrade some projects, some not

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution file with a bunch of C# projects. For some of the projects, VS2017 urges me to upgrade the project to a later version. We are in a transition phase where one solution needs VS2017 while the rest of our code base is still using VS2015, hence we don't want to upgrade yet.

I do not understand why some projects are triggering this prompt and some not. They have the same ToolsVersion, ProjectTypeGuids, TargetFrameworkVersion etc.

I am looking for a way to modify the projects so that VS2017 shuts up until we are ready to make the full move to VS2017.

Comment: VS 2017 shouldnt upgrade the project files, unless you have .NET Core Projects. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944571/is-visual-studio-2017-backwards-compatible-with-visual-studio-2015-solutions

Comment: It shouldn't, and I can just cancel the prompt and everything works. But the prompt makes it easy for developers to accidentally upgrade the project, breaking VS2015 support. (The upgrade changes ToolsVersion to 15)

Comment: What is the project type which VS2017 wants to upgrade? Since you have code base is still using VS2015 and don not want to upgrade  to VS2017, Why do not you continue to develop your project on VS2015? Then upgrade it when you ready.

Comment: .NET framework class lib. Other projects in one solution requires 2017, and the solutions share projects.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060441 it is an answer to the same question.

Comment: No, that is a different issue. In the end I solved this by migrating to the new style C# projects, which brings along a lot of other benefits.