# Is it recommended to use Visual Studio 2017 with older solutions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

At my company, we're using 3 different versions of Visual Studio:

- VS2013 (very old projects that were never migrated, and might never will)
- VS2015 (most of the projects, including some of the projects that were created with VS2013 but were migrated at some stage)
- VS2017 (new projects)

I always open a solution with its corresponding Visual Studio version - i.e. I'd open a VS2013 solution with Visual Studio 2013 IDE, and so on. I configured the builds on Visual Studio Team Services the same way.

Today I was having a chat with a co-worker who told me he was working on a VS2015 using VS2017 IDE. All projects in that solution are targetting .NET v4.5.1. One the one hand if we use VS2017 we can take advantage of the new features, bug fixes etc of the latest version of the IDE but I was wondering if this is recommended, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using VS2017 with an older version? What do you usually do and why?

PS: Just to be clear, the question is not if the solution should be upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio or not. I'm just wondering if it's recommended to use one version of the IDE over another.

Comment: I use VS2017 Enterprise for solutions  > 10 years old targeting .NET 2.0 and I don't see any problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944571/is-visual-studio-2017-backwards-compatible-with-visual-studio-2015-solutions

Comment: I am using VS2015 with .Net framework 4.5.2 and 4.6, working fine. I have tested VS2017 as well and it works fine too.

Comment: There are issues if you use new language features that aren't available to previous versions of the IDE and you then want to open again in earlier version of VS

Comment: Sooner or later you must.  Might as well be today.

Comment: @phuzi yes that's true - in this case, one of the developers was using the new out parameter functionality in a .NET v4.5.1 project (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/out-parameter-in-c-sharp-7/). The solution was compiling using VS2017, but not using VS2015.

Comment: @RuiJarimba It's not something a dev should do on their own when there are other people in the team. It should be a group decision so that everyone  is "on the same page".

Comment: @phuzi I completely agree, that was exactly the point what started this whole discussion in my team

Comment: Thanks for the link, @HansPassant. I see now that VS2017 is more backwards-compatibility "friendly" than the previous versions of Visual Studio.